# I am struggling to position/ remove whitespace from duplicate components

Tags: html, css, reactjs

[image: The Circled Section Is what I want to stay at the top]

### Here you will see the start of the *NotesFromCoachesForWrestlers* component circled

> The problem is When the notes on the component on the left increase the component on the right adds whitespace which I don't want, if anything I would want it at the bottom of the component.

#### PLease note so far I have tried:

- *position: relative* and *top: 0* on the containing div
- It seems the card div with class card-body is growing
- - Even if I set the div to have a height of 50px it still grows tho

```html
 <div className="col-12">
      <div className="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-around">
        <div className="card my-1 p-1 col-sm-12 col-md-6" style={{ border: "1.3px solid black" }}>
          <div className="card-body">
            <GradingDashboardMadeByLuke UID={wrestler1UID} />
            <div
              className="card-text"
              style={{ color: "black", fontSize: "smaller" }}
            >
              The previous 5 Logins for {props.wrestler1FullName} were:{" "}
              {allLoginsForWrestler1.map((login) => {
                return (
                  <p>
                    <Moment fromNow>{login.login_was_created_at}</Moment> -{" "}
                  </p>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <NotesFromCoachesForWrestlers UID={wrestler1UID} />
            <SubmitNoteForWrestler
              wrestlerID={wrestler1UID}
              wrestlerFullName={props.wrestler1FullName}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          className="card my-1 p-1 col-sm-12 col-md-6"
          style={{ border: "1.3px solid #ff7824" }}
        >
          <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title">
              <strong>{/*{props.first_name} {personalInfo.last_name}*/}</strong>
            </h5>
            <GradingDashboardMadeByLuke UID={wrestler2UID} />
            <div
              className="card-text"
              style={{ color: "black", fontSize: "smaller" }}
            >
              The previous 5 Logins for {props.wrestler2FullName} were:{" "}
              {allLoginsForWrestler2.map((login) => {
                return (
                  <p>
                    <Moment fromNow>{login.login_was_created_at}</Moment> -{" "}
                  </p>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="mb-auto">
            <NotesFromCoachesForWrestlers UID={wrestler2UID} />
            <SubmitNoteForWrestler
              wrestlerID={wrestler2UID}
              wrestlerFullName={props.wrestler2FullName}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: [height: max-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-content) should do the trick. Another prop you should check is `flex-grow`. That's typically the culprit in flex children growing. Set it to `0`. Last, but not least, setting `margin-bottom: auto` on the lower element is also likely to fix the issue. Side note: your current code is not enough to repro and is therefore useless. Consider creating a [mcve] (codesandbox.io or similar).

Comment: How do I do that if I am using react? Do I just do my best to copy the problem in javascript and html

Comment: Also thank you very much flex-grow to zero did the trick weirdly enough, I thought flex-grow is zero by default?

Comment: You can start a react project on codesandbox.io (that's why I suggested it). It's an online multi-file node-like environment. The neat trick about it is you can copy/paste your package.json and boom: you have everything working. That doesn't mean you should repro your entire project. Just enough for the current issue.